# How to highlight and get informations from elasticsearch-dsl search in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm using django-elasticsearch-dsl. 
I have already index datas and set up some queries on them.

Here is an example of query in my views :

`q = HemisticheDocument.search().query(operation, field="value")`

Then after I have :

`listHem = [hit for hit in q[:q.count()]`

I have results. When operation is "match", I have no problem because it is an exact term that I am looking for.

However, when I use `"fuzzy"` as my operation, I would like to know if it possible for any hit :

- To highlight or extract the term (which may not be the exact one) that has been found in the hit.
- To get the score of it.

I would put them in a dictionary for other uses.

Thank you in advance. Hope the question is clear enough.